# Rasa train_init.py gives sklearn_crfsuite pacakge error

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

i am implementing RASA weatherbot from this [link](https://vimeo.com/254777331)
i am getting error when trying to run RASA train_init. I am getting below error.

```
Exception: Not all required packages are installed. To use this pipeline, you need to install the missing dependencies. Please install sklearn_crfsuite
```

I have sklearn_crfsuite installed but still getting this error. I don't know how to fix please help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you are getting it looks like your system doesn't find the sklearn_crfsuite installation. Are you running the script in a virtual env? If yes, chances are that crfsuite was installed locally and therefore not available for a virtual env.

I would also recommend checking out an updated version of this tutorial [here](https://github.com/JustinaPetr/Weatherbot_Tutorial/tree/master/Full%20Code%20%5BLatest%20release%20of%20Rasa%20NLU%20and%20Rasa%20Core%5D) (the info in the video is still relevant, but the code in the repo is more up-to-date).